# How to direct a Flow to two different Visualforce (finishLocation)

Tags: class, flow

I am fighting a flow and I want to know if it is possible.

The result of the flow is a variable ContactId

I want that when the flows ends:
- if the ContactId is null, the finishLocation should be https://c.cs22.visual.force.com/apex/Form4
- if the ContactId is not null, the finishLocation should be https://c.cs22.visual.force.com/apex/Form1?Id=ContactId

I found this, but I have no idea how to changed. Can someone help me?Thank you all for your time!

Visualforce

```
<apex:page Controller="AddendumEntryController" TabStyle="Addendum__c">
    <flow:interview name="Addendum_Entry" interview="{!AddendumEntry}" finishLocation="{!backToAddendum}" >
        <apex:param name="vOpportunityId" value="{!opptyId}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>**strong text**
```

Class

```
public with sharing class AddendumEntryController {

    public ID getoppId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('oid');
    public Flow.Interview.Addendum_Entry AddendumEntry{get;set;}

    public String getOpptyId(){ return getoppId; }
    public ID returnId = getoppId;

    public PageReference getBackToAddendum(){

        if(AddendumEntry != null) returnId = AddendumEntry.vAddendumId;

        PageReference send = new PageReference('/' + returnId);
        send.setRedirect(true);
        return send;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a Fault then add an error handler for when the `ContactId = null`. The [Force.com Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/) takes you through an example of creating a Flow in Step 8 where they create a Fault, then handle it a Fault Screen.

What I suspect you need to do is use the same concept, except instead of creating the Fault screen, add the logic to send the User to the alternate finish location. Either that or else you'll simply need to add a branch logic in your flow (a decision tree) based on the condition of whether your variable is null. If if true, go to the alternate finish location. If false, go to the Contact finish location. Just drag the icon for that into your flow builder.

For more on building Flows, I highly recommend the webinars on [The Power of Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/power_of_flow). That page also has many links to other related resources.

Comment: Thank you for you time! the flow works, my problem is when creating the classes to define different finishLocation...

Comment: I recommend you create your finish locations from within the flow builder. You could even create a "dummy flow" to simulate the decision tree at end of your flow to generate the controller class you need to help define the two finish locations.